# setLevel okhttp LoggingInterceptor deprecated

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

setLevel(okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level)' is deprecated

what should replace with setLevel? to remove the deprecated issue

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to the documentation "Moved to var. Replace setLevel(...) with level(...) to fix Java",

Replace `setLevel(...)` with `level(...)` will fix this issue

in Java:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.level(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
```

in Kotlin

```
val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: same in Kotlin:  

val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

Answer (score 0):

**for Kotlin**

replace :

```
val logger: HttpLoggingInterceptor =
HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)  //Logging Interceptor
```

with :

```
val logger = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
logger.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
```

Add your inceptor to `okHttpClient`

```
val okkHttpclient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(networkConnectionInterceptor)
                .addInterceptor(logger)
                .build()
```

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin, use the apply function and then setLevel using the level property.

```
 private val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
        level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    }

    var client : OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor).build()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.