# Cannot setLevel in OkHttp3 : Level has private access and SetLevel is deprecated

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

The method `setLevel` of the `HttpLoggingInterceptor` is deprecated.

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56840495/setlevel-okhttp-logginginterceptor-deprecated) it is sufficient to replace setLevel(...) with Level(...) but then again, I get that level has private access in `OkHttp3`.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Currently using:

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.1")
```

[EDIT]
I solved my problem by cleaning all the versions in my Gradle File and in particular by adding 
`def OkHttpVersion = "4.2.1"
 implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$OkHttpVersion")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by cleaning all the versions in my Gradle File and in particular by adding 
`def OkHttpVersion = "4.2.1"
 implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$OkHttpVersion")`

Answer (score 1):

I'd check you aren't mixing okhttp3 versions.  .level(newLevel) is what you want.

[image: setting level]

Comment: What do you mean by checking "mixing okhttp3 versions"?

Comment: I meant JAR versions.  Are you sure that 4.2.1 is used everywhere?  Your code looks correct and matches the working example I gave.

Comment: I am prone to think that there is some issue with Retrofit as i just read OkHttp dependency is already shipped with Retrofit 2 dependency but I didn't find a way yet to see which OkHttp version Retrofit is using